# Join JSON data in pig scripting

Tags: json, apache-pig

I have following data.

emp.json

```
{id:1, name:'abc', deptid:10}

{id:2, name:'def', deptid:20}

{id:3, name:'ghi', deptid:10}

{id:4, name:'jkm', deptid:20}
```

dept.json

```
{dept_id:10, dept_name:'PIG'}

{dept_id:20, dept_name:'JSON'}
```

I have following script.

```
emp_data = LOAD '/user/JsonExample/emp.json' USING JsonLoader('id:int,name:chararray, deptid:int');

dept_data = LOAD '/user/JsonExample/dept.json' USING JsonLoader('dept_id:int,dept_name:chararray'); 

emp_data = FOREACH emp_data GENERATE id,name as name,deptid;

dept_data = FOREACH dept_data GENERATE dept_id,dept_name;

joined_data = JOIN emp_data by (deptid), dept_data by (dept_id);

joined_data = FOREACH joined_data GENERATE id,name,deptid,dept_name;

STORE joined_data INTO 'join_output.json' USING JsonStorage();
```

I got following output.

```
{emp_data::id:1, emp_data::name:'abc',emp_data::dept_id:10, dept_data::dept_name:'PIG'}

{emp_data::id:2, emp_data::name:'def',emp_data::dept_id:20, dept_data::dept_name:'JSON'}

{emp_data::id:3, emp_data::name:'ghi',emp_data::dept_id:10, dept_data::dept_name:'PIG'}

{emp_data::id:4, emp_data::name:'jkm',emp_data::dept_id:20, dept_data::dept_name:'JSON'}
```

But I want following output.

```
{id:1, name:'abc',dept_id:10, dept_name:'PIG'}

{id:2, name:'def',dept_id:20, dept_name:'JSON'}

{id:3, name:'ghi',dept_id:10, dept_name:'PIG'}

{id:4, name:'jkm',dept_id:20, dept_name:'JSON'}
```

Please let me know how to get required output.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
joined_data = FOREACH joined_data GENERATE 
   emp_data::id as id,
   emp_data::name as name,
   emp_data::deptid as deptid,
   dept_data::dept_name as dept_name;
```